# Flask's routes and POST method to Django

Tags: python, django

I have this fragment of code in Flask

```
@app.route('/search', methods = ['POST'])
def search():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       results_arr = []
       img_path = request.form.get('img')
```

How to make this in Django or where I can read about it?

Comment: read Django documentation

Answer (score 0):

The route in the flask fragment will be put up in the `urls.py` with an entry which might look as follows

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index , name='index'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

and in the `views.py` you'll have a function which will look as follows assuming the corresponding HTML form has enctype `multipart/form-data` and the html is a file upload.

```
<input type="file" name="myimage">
```

The corresponding function assuming you've set the `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` in the settings can be translated as:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage    

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myimage']:
        results_arr = []
        imagefile = request.FILES['myimage']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(imagefile.name, imagefile)
        file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return render(request, 'templateToRender.html', { 'filepath': file_url }) # in case you want to show the user the URL of the upload.
```

You could also use `forms.py` an example is provided in their documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/file-uploads/)